# How to fetch Only Uppercase values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two values For example:

I have a question as below

```
   A
----------
1) gamecop@rochester.rr.com

2) GAMECOP@ROCHESTER.RR.COM
```

I want only the Upper case value as output like below

```
 OUTPUT : A
----------
GAMECOP@ROCHESTER.RR.COM
```

Answer (score 6):

By default, Oracle is case sensitive.  So you can do this comparison:

```
select *
from t
where a = upper(a);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff !!